# Fast consecutive prime multiplication

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, algorithms, multiplicative-function

Are there any fast algorithms for multiplying consecutive prime numbers? I found this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1706931/consecutive-prime-numbers-multiplication-pattern) about a pattern when multiplying consecutive primes. I was wondering if there is a multiplication algorithm just for prime numbers based on patterns.

Comment: For arbitrary prime numbers ("just for prime numbers") it just amounts to  the fast multiplication of integers, I think. See [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwj_4Mrz3eD0AhUE-6QKHSc_CAoQFnoECAUQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fweb.maths.unsw.edu.au%2F~davidharvey%2Ftalks%2Fmult.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2QvRoNIm102ur_QDDgPUIs).

Comment: No, the multiplication cannot be accelerated by exploiting the patterns of the prime numbers , in particular because there is no general pattern between consecutive prime numbers.